# "Under your sight"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I'm thinking about a motto (slogan) for a company which is trying to give its customers a complete view of the market. I'm thinking of this motto:

> Everything, Everywhere, **Under your sight**

Is it grammatically correct? I mean, can we use *under* for *sight*?

Comment: No. Things can by ***within** [someone's] sight/hearing*, but not ***under*** it. I think that's basic General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, seems that your answer is what I wanted. Please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Also, there's no Need to capitalize Random words like That. Title case or sentence case, pick one and then stick to it.

Comment: Under your control, yes, but not everything under your sight.

Answer (score 2):

It does not really work. To me, *under my sight* actually sounds like it's hidden from me. It's similar to the expression *right under my nose*, which implies that something is in front of you but you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really such a thing as complete market view, to be had. The company could certainly hope to provide lots of market insights or even an analysis.
As long as you're open to suggestions, I think that something around enablement or empowering of the clients would be more effective. I suggest "hone/zero in on best stocks" or something along those lines.